# Ob_start not catching output file

Tags: php, phpdocx

I am trying to generate report and upload it. Problem is that when function that generates the file ends with readfile(), it just downloads the file even if I put `ob_start()` before the function call. So I don't understand why `ob_start` is not catching It.

Problem should be here

1. I call `ob_start()`
2. Then I call function that outputs file like this

   `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.' .
               'wordprocessingml.document');
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileNameDownload . '"');
           header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
           header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName . '.' . $this->_extension));
           readfile($fileName . '.' . $this->_extension);`
3. After previous function call I put 
   `$content = ob_get_contents();`

and 4. `ob_end_clen()`

I would expect that with `readfile()` the function will start to write into buffer, but instead it outputs the file for download

Comment: Show us code otherwise all I can see is a duplicate of something like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938822/how-do-i-assign-content-from-readfile-into-a-variable

Comment: I edited it a bit, hope that's enough, because it's few hundreads line of code otherwise.

Comment: Without echoing the buffer content, have you reviewed what is actually downloaded at the end of script execution? My thoughts is you're getting  a header conflict. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111179/how-do-headers-work-with-output-buffering-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fact that headers are being set, and not being captured by the output buffer, that you may need to cancel them out, especially since `Content-Disposition: attachment` is setting the response to be a forced download.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script **(other than headers)**, instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

Therefore if the function sets:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.' . 'wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileNameDownload . '"');
```

you will need to do cancel it out after you've ended the output buffering capture, ie:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
```